# AngularJS - Calling function in directive when a 2-way bound value changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive all setup with 2-way data binding on the attributes using `=` and I can see everything is working well with that. Now I'm stuck at the need to call a function within the directive whenever one of my bound attributes changes in the parent scope, and I can't figure out how to pull that off.

I'm basically creating a version of the ui checkbox button that works with arrays of objects. You pass the directive an `allowed` array (which contains all the different options) and an `applied` array (which contains the same objects from `allowed`). For checking if an object is in the `allowed` array I have another array that is the just the `id` properties. Within the directive this is working great, but if the `applied` array changes outside of the directive the `id` array never gets updated.

**The Directive:**

```js
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.directive('btnCheckboxGroup', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        // controller: DirCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'btnCheckboxGroup.html',
        scope: {
            allowed: '=',
            applied: '=',
            id: '=',
            title: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){ 
            scope.abp = [];

            // this works right away, but how do I run it when the parent scope updates it?
            angular.forEach(scope.applied, function(obj){
               scope.abp.push( obj[scope.id] ); 
            });

            scope.addRemove = function(a){
                var index = scope.abp.indexOf(a[scope.id]);

                // doesn't exist, add it
                if(index === -1){
                    scope.abp.push(a[scope.id]);
                    scope.applied.push(a);

                // does exist, remove it
                } else {
                    scope.abp.splice(index, 1);
                    for(var i in scope.applied){
                        if(scope.applied[i][scope.id]==a[scope.id]){
                            scope.applied.splice(i,1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }// end addRemove()

        }
    };
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLSJY/)**

I've tried lots of variations of things like `scope.$watch`, `attrs.$observe`, and attempted at one point to try one-way data-binding with `@` and that made lots of things crash.

So whats the magic I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a third parameter to $watch to change the way it compares the old and the new value. See the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

```
$watch(watchExpression, [listener], [objectEquality]);
```

If you set this to `true`, it will pick up changes in the content of the array and not only when the array reference changes. This does have a performance impact (depending on the length of the array). Checking only the length of the array does not cover the case where the number of elements stay the same but the elements themselves do change.

In your case you would need to do something like this:

```
 scope.$watch(
     "applied", 
     function() {
         scope.abp = [];
         angular.forEach(scope.applied, function(obj){
             scope.abp.push( obj[scope.id] ); 
         });
     },
     true);
```

Comment: should have known it would be something small that I already tried with one tiny little tweak

Comment: Another thing to note is that you don't use the `elem` and `attrs` method parameters. All of your code could (and should) be put in a controller.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on that one, makes sense. The second portion of what I'm doing in the directive does make use of `elem` and `attrs` but it could probably be reworked not to. Is there an advantage to having it in a controller, other than "it's the angular way". If that's the reason, then my next question is why is it the angular way.

Comment: One reason why Angular makes it easier to create maintainable and testable applications is because interactions with the DOM are isolated from the rest of the logic. Where are they put? In the link and compile function of directives. It's possible to interact with the scope in the link function because you need to be able to link the DOM and your scopes somewhere. So it is possible to put all your scope logic in the link function, but you would end up with a less maintainable application.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
        scope.$watch(function() {
             return scope.applied.length;   
        }, function(val) {
            console.log(val);
            console.log(scope.applied);
        });
```

The array on scope doesn't change but its length does, so if you were using the string-variant of `$watch` it won't fire, but using a function and looking at the length of the array will. More on this in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)